# confuse about parameter 'tokens_length' of elmo model in tensorflow hub

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, embedding, elmo

I'm looking the ELMo model in tensorflow hub and, I'm not very clear about what does **tokens_length = [6, 5]** means in the flow example use:
(https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2)

```
elmo = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=True)
tokens_input = [["the", "cat", "is", "on", "the", "mat"],
                ["dogs", "are", "in", "the", "fog", ""]]
tokens_length = [6, 5]
embeddings = elmo(
    inputs={
        "tokens": tokens_input,
        "sequence_len": tokens_length
    },
    signature="tokens",
    as_dict=True)["elmo"]
```

It does't like the max length for the input token sentence, does't like [max number of words for each sentence, numbers of sentence] either, that makes me confused.
Could someone explain this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example has length `6` and the second example has length `5`:. i.e.

"*the cat is on the mat*" is 6 words long but "*dogs are in the fog*" is only 5 words long. The extra empty string in the input does add a little confusion :-/

If you read the docs on that page it explains why this is needed (**bold** font is mine)

> With the tokens signature, the module takes tokenized sentences as input. The input tensor is a string tensor with shape [batch_size, **max_length**] and an int32 tensor with shape [batch_size] corresponding to the sentence length. The **length input is necessary to exclude padding in the case of sentences with varying length**.

Comment: aha,thanks!  One more question,  does I have to give the valid length for each sentence when using the tokens signature? e.g. the training data-set  has 100 samples, and tokens_length is given like a 100 dimensional vector recording the length for every sample. if that is true, it seems like to be some kind of trouble :(

Comment: Glad to help! :-) That's my understanding, yes. Shouldn't be too much trouble to count the words in each sample though, no?

Comment: emmm...no, not too much trouble, but still need to do some works. Maybe as a beginner, i'm just 'spoiled', haha

Comment: Then is it possible to write the code like this?

embeddings = elmo(inputs={"tokens": tokens_input, "sequence_len": [len(sample) - sample.count("") for sample in tokens_input]}, signature="tokens", as_dict=True)["elmo"]

This returns the length of each sentence without the padding.